# How to store users data after authentication to get user specific http requests. angular8 and node.js

Tags: node.js, angular, http, authentication

Im working on the frontend portion of a MEAN app and i'm lost on where to go next. I want to be able to make calls to user specific data after the authentication process is complete.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Can't you use sessionStorage to store user info?

Comment: After login store authentication token in cookie/local storage. When user refresh the page get the user details. to share details between components use observer or ngx  store. No need to store user details

Comment: Read up on JWT and the package https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-jwt This is a topic well out of scope for a StackOverflow question.